# OpenCV smoothen corners of a drawn polygon

Tags: python, opencv

I draw this mask with `cv2.drawContours`. I need edges to be round. How should I do it?

[image: mask]

Comment: Try morphological operation with an elliptical kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what Jeru Luke suggests in the comments. You need dilate, erode, dilate. Just Opening (erode, dilate) will only affect convex corners, same with Closing and concave corners.

```py
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (101,101))
out = cv.dilate(im, kernel)
out = cv.erode(out, kernel, iterations=2)
out = cv.dilate(out, kernel)
```

result vs. difference as `(im >> 1) + (out >> 1)`:

[image: morphology] [image: difference image]

---

If your polygon has **those 13 corners** and it's literally a list of 13 points, then Hihikomori's answer will fail. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate... this is with *1 iteration* instead of 120:

[image: fails on sparse contours]

It fails because the contour isn't a dense list of points but merely the corners of the polygon. That approach requires points to have roughly equal spacing between them, and to be fairly dense.

Comment: The way I call `cv2.findContours` gives enough points for a good result. Also if there is a "list of 13 points", the additional points can be obtained by interpolation. Potentially, "convolving the contour" works faster because there is less data to process. Also the convolutional kernel can be bigger, that can reduce the number of iteration.

Comment: Time complexity for this method is O(n^2). But working with contour gives O(n), and with some update of code less depends on image size.

Comment: I *know* you called findContours on the picture of the contour OP just drew. CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE didn't remove as many points as it could, had the contour contained more axis-aligned edges. I also know contours can be bulked up with intermediate points. -- I'm not up to date on the most efficient algorithms for morphology operations. I believe for some slight approximations there are algorithms that are very much better than squared.

Comment: Yes CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE is incorrect, must be CHAIN_APPROX_NONE. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("path/to/image")

img_gray=img[:,:,0]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Split contour data to components
contour=contours[0].reshape(contours[0].shape[0],-1).astype(np.float32)
cnt_len = contour.shape[0]
cnt_x= contour[:,0]
cnt_y= contour[:,1]

# Extend contour to preserve boundary conditions.
cnt_x = np.concatenate((cnt_x,cnt_x,cnt_x),axis=0)
cnt_y = np.concatenate((cnt_y,cnt_y,cnt_y),axis=0)

# Blurring the contour
amount = 120
for _ in range(amount):
    cnt_x= np.convolve(cnt_x,[0.33,0.34,0.33],"same")
    cnt_y= np.convolve(cnt_y,[0.33,0.34,0.33],"same")

# Composing contour to draw with opencv
convolved_cnt = np.empty((cnt_x.shape[0],2),np.int32)
convolved_cnt[:,0]=cnt_x
convolved_cnt[:,1]=cnt_y
convolved_cnt=convolved_cnt[cnt_len:cnt_len*2]

cv2.drawContours(img, [convolved_cnt], -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow("",img)
cv2.waitKey()
```